# Homogeneous space and nice manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, quotient-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

We know that 
$$
 O(n+1)/O(n) \simeq SO(n+1)/SO(n) \simeq  S^n,
$$
based on the result of [homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space).

Also
$$
 PO(n+1)/PO(n) \simeq  P^n,
$$
$P^n$ is the projective space.

Do we have similar nice results for the following:
$$
 U(n+1)/U(n) \simeq?
$$
and 
$$
 SU(n+1)/SU(n) \simeq?
$$
$$
 Sp(n+1)/Sp(n) \simeq?
$$

Comment: What is $PO(n)$?

Comment: Projectivized orthogonal group?

Comment: Have you looked in Husemolller or Steenrod? I think that all this stuff's discussed in the first few chapters of those books, but it's been a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are all spheres.  The relevant technical lemma is the follow:

> Suppose $G$ is a compact Lie group which acts smoothly and transitively on a manifold $M$.  Let $p\in M$ and set $G_p = \{g\in G: gp = p\}$.  Then $G/G_p$ is canonically diffeomorphic to $M$ via the diffeomorphism $g G_p\mapsto gp$.

For $G = U(n+1)$ or $G = SU(n+1)$, the relevant $M$ is the the sphere $S^{2n+1}\subseteq \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, where the $G$ action is given by usual matrix multiplication on vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.  For $G = Sp(n+1)$, $M = S^{4n+3}\subseteq \mathbb{H}^{n+1}$.

One must verify that the $G$ action is transitive, and then compute $G_p$ for a single $p$.

Technically, the notation $U(n+1)/U(n)$, etc, is ambiguous until one specifies an embedding $U(n)\rightarrow U(n+1)$.  Fr the examples at hand, it is often the case (but not always the case) that there is a unique embedding $G_p\rightarrow G$, up to conjugacy.  Conjugate embeddings always give rise to diffeomorphic manifolds:  $G/G_p\cong  G/gG_p g^{-1}$.

One the other hand, the two embeddings of $U(1)$ into $U(2)$ given by $z\mapsto \operatorname{diag}(z,1)$ or $\operatorname{diag}(z,z)$ give rise to homogeneous spaces which are not even homotopy equivalent.     One has an analogous result for $Sp(1)\rightarrow Sp(2)$.  But these are the only exceptions: e.g. $U(2)$ embeds into $U(3)$ in only way one, up to conjugacy.

Comment: Thanks +1, how about $\mathbb{CP}^{n+1}/\mathbb{CP}^n$?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is never a Lie group for any $n > 0$.  What do you mean by your notation?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}P^1 \simeq S^2$ is a 2-sphere. It is a complex projective space

Comment: typo fixed -thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a sphere, but not a Lie group.  (Only $S^0, S^1, S^3$ are Lie groups)

Comment: Can one consider the homogeneous space for the projective space? like $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ and $\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{R}P^{n}$?

Comment: One can consider the topological quotient $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^n$ for some prescribed embedding $\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{n+1}$, but that is very different from Lie theoretic kind of quotient.

Comment: Thanks I will accept your answer in a few days if no better ones.

Comment: I posted a new question in the link.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2867622/79069