# Homogeneous space and quotient space for complex projective spaces

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups, projective-space, quotient-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

We know that 
$$
 O(n+1)/O(n) \simeq SO(n+1)/SO(n) \simeq  S^n,
$$
based on the result of [homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space).

Also
$$
 PO(n+1)/PO(n) \simeq  P^n,
$$
$P^n$ is the projective space.

These are in some sense [spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2867112/79069).

If we embed the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^n$ into $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}$, we may be able to define the quotient space 
$$
{\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}}/{\mathbb{C}P^{n}} \simeq ?
$$

- Do we have simpler expressions for the above "manifolds" or "quotient space"?
- Homotopy group $\pi_i({\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}}/{\mathbb{C}P^{n}})=?$

Attempt: Note that ${\mathbb{C}P^{n}}=S^{2n+1}/U(1)$, so for 
 ${\mathbb{C}P^{1}}\simeq S^2$ and  ${\mathbb{C}P^{0}}\simeq 0$, 
so
$$\pi_i({\mathbb{C}P^{1}}/{\mathbb{C}P^{0}})=\pi_i(S^2/0)=\pi_i(S^2),$$
which homotopy group is known.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^n$ is typically understood to be the quotient space where we identify $\mathbb{C}P^n$ to a point.  (But not other identifications are made).  Is this what you meant?  If so, for the usual embedding of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ into $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}$, $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^{2n+2}$.  That said, as a general rule, for $N\subseteq M$ closed manifolds, there is no reason for $M/N$ to be homotopy equivalent to a manifold.

Comment: thanks - if this is correct - this counts as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^n$ is typically understood to be the quotient space where we identify $\mathbb{C}P^n$ to a point. (But not other identifications are made).

For the usual embedding of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ into $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}$, given by mapping homogeneous coordinates $[z_0:z_1:...:z_n]\mapsto [z_0:z_1:...:z_n: z_{n+1}]$, $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^{2n+2}$.  One way to see this is as follows.

First, let $Z_i = \frac{z_i}{z_{n+1}}$ (assuming $z_{n+1}\neq 0$).  Also, let $Z = \sum_{i=0}^n |Z_i|^2$.

Then, we map $\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}\rightarrow S^{2n+2}$ via $$(z_0:...:z_{n+1})\mapsto \begin{cases} \left(\frac{2Z_0}{1+Z}, \frac{2Z_1}{1+Z}, ..., \frac{2Z_n}{1+Z}, \frac{-1+Z}{1+Z} \right) & z_{n+1}\neq 0 \\ (0,0,..,0,1) & z_{n+1} = 0  \end{cases}.$$

The case that $z_{n+1} = 0$ corresponds exactly to a point being in $\mathbb{C}P^n$.  As a result, $f$ is constant on $\mathbb{C}P^n$ so gives a map $\overline{f}:\mathbb{C}P^{n+1}/\mathbb{C}P^n\rightarrow S^{2n+2}$.  This map is a homeomorphism.

Finally, typically, there is no reason for $M/N$ to be a manifold even when $M$ and $N$ are really nice.  For example, if $N$ is the equator on $M = S^2$, then $M/N$ is homeomorphic to $S^2\wedge S^2$, which is not a manifold due to the wedge point.

Comment: I post a new question maybe you may be also able to answer.

Comment: I don't think it's worth bumping this answer to edit, but I just noticed my last sentence should have $S^2\vee S^2$, not $S^2\wedge S^2$.