# Homogeneous space and quotient space for real projective spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, projective-space, quotient-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

We know that 
$$
 O(n+1)/O(n) \simeq SO(n+1)/SO(n) \simeq  S^n,
$$
based on the result of [homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space).

Also
$$
 PO(n+1)/PO(n) \simeq  P^n,
$$
$P^n$ is the projective space.

These are in some sense [spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2867112/79069).

If we embed the real projective space $\mathbb{C}P^n$ into $\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}$, we may be able to define the quotient space

> $$
> {\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}}/{\mathbb{R}P^{n}} \simeq ?
> $$
>
> - Do we have simpler expressions for the above "manifolds" or "quotient space"?
> - Homotopy group $\pi_i({\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}}/{\mathbb{R}P^{n}})=?$

**My Attempt**: Note that ${\mathbb{R}P^{n}}$ is diffeomorphic to the submanifold of $R^{(n+1)^2}$ consisting of all symmetric $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrices of trace 1 that are also idempotent linear transformations.
, so for 
 ${\mathbb{R}P^{2}}\simeq SO(3)$, ${\mathbb{R}P^{1}}\simeq S^1 \simeq SO(2)$ and  ${\mathbb{R}P^{0}}\simeq 0$, 
so
$$\pi_i({\mathbb{R}P^{2}}/{\mathbb{R}P^{1}})=\pi_i(SO(3)/SO(2))=?,$$
$$\pi_i({\mathbb{R}P^{1}}/{\mathbb{R}P^{0}})=\pi_i(S^1),$$
Also 
the [$\pi_i({\mathbb{R}P^{n}})$ can be found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space#Homotopy_groups).

Comment: Use the argument I gave in the $\mathbb{C}P^n$ case.  It's almost verbatim the same.

Comment: It is not true that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^n)$ is $(-1)^{n+1}$. The latter object is not even a group.

Comment: Also, it is $\mathbb{R}P^3\cong SO(3)$, rather than $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: Note that there are embeddings $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}\hookrightarrow SO(n)$ defined by sending a line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a certain reflection (see James's "Topology of Stiefel Manifolds", for instance). Compare the cofibration sequence $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n/\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ with the fibration $SO(n)\rightarrow SO(n+1)\rightarrow S^n$ using the previous embeddings, and see what you can figure out.