# Homogeneous space and quotient space for spin groups

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups, quotient-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

We know that 
$$
 O(n+1)/O(n) \simeq SO(n+1)/SO(n) \simeq  S^n,
$$
based on the result of [homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space).

These are in some sense [spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2867112/79069).

If we embed the spin group $Spin(n)$ into $Spin(n+1)$, we may be able to define the quotient space

> $$
> {Spin(n+1)}/{Spin(n)} \simeq ?
> $$
>
> - Do we have simpler expressions for the above "manifolds" or "quotient space"?

My Trial/Attempt:
We know that 
$$
Spin(2)\simeq U(1)\simeq SO(2) \simeq S^1
$$ 
$$
Spin(3)\simeq SU(2)\simeq S^3
$$ 
$$
Spin(4)\simeq SU(2) \times SU(2)
$$ 
$$
Spin(5)\simeq Sp(2)
$$ 
$$
Spin(6)\simeq SU(4),
$$ 
while
$$
Spin(3)/Spin(2) \simeq  S^3/ S^1  \simeq  S^2
$$
$$
Spin(4)/Spin(3) \simeq  (SU(2) \times SU(2))/ S^3 \simeq  (S^3  \times S^3 )/ S^3   \simeq  S^3
$$
Could we obtain the generic formulas for ${Spin(n+1)}/{Spin(n)} \simeq ?
$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that $SO(n+1)$ acts smoothly and transitively on $S^n$ with isotropy subgroup $SO(n)$, so $SO(n+1)/SO(n)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n$. Now note that $\operatorname{Spin}(n+1)$ also acts smoothly and transitively on $S^n$ by first mapping to $SO(n+1)$. The isotropy subgroup is the subgroup of $\operatorname{Spin}(n+1)$ which projects to $SO(n) \subset SO(n+1)$, this is precisely $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$. Therefore $\operatorname{Spin}(n+1)/\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n$.

More generally, suppose $G$ is a compact Lie group which acts smoothly and transitively on a smooth manifold $M$ with isotropy subgroup $H$. If $\hat{G}$ is a compact Lie group and $\pi : \hat{G} \to G$ is a surjective Lie group homomorphism, then $\hat{G}$ acts smoothly and transitively on $M$ with isotropy subgroup $\pi^{-1}(H)$, so both $G/H$ and $\hat{G}/\pi^{-1}(H)$ are diffeomorphic to $M$.

Comment: Thanks, this is really a clean answer. +1.